# Swift: UISearchBar, find Person by NSPredicate first or last name

Tags: swift, xcode, uisearchbar, nspredicate

I am trying to find a Person with a UISearchbar by last or fist name.

And I have implemented the following Code:

```
   func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()

        let searchTerm = searchBar.text
        if searchTerm != "" {

            let predicateLastname = NSPredicate(format: "nachname CONTAINS[cd] %@,", searchTerm!)
            let precicateFirstname = NSPredicate(format: "vorname CONTAINS [cd] %@", searchTerm!)

            let predicateOr = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .or, subpredicates: [predicateLastname, precicateFirstname])

            request.predicate = predicateOr

            let sortDecriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "nachname", ascending: true)
            let sortDecriptor2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "vorname", ascending: true)
            request.sortDescriptors = [sortDecriptor, sortDecriptor2]
        }
        do {
            let personArray = try managedObjectContext!.fetch(request) as! [NSManagedObject]

        } catch {
            ("Error searching person \(error)")
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

If I run the program an error occurs:

```
2019-12-10 17:07:56.641142+0100 HappyBirthdayMom[13999:810809] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "nachname CONTAINS[cd] %@,"'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c4f02e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff50b97b20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Foundation                          0x00007fff257d7a31 +[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:arguments:] + 164
    3   libswiftFoundation.dylib            0x00007fff515388bf $sSo12NSExpressionC10FoundationE6format_ABSSh_s7CVarArg_pdtcfCTm + 543
    4   HappyBirthdayMom                    0x000000010797bc1c $s16HappyBirthdayMom20MasterViewControllerC28searchBarSearchButtonClickedyySo08UISearchH0CF + 1004
    5   HappyBirthdayMom                    0x000000010797c944 $s16HappyBirthdayMom20MasterViewControllerC28searchBarSearchButtonClickedyySo08UISearchH0CFTo + 68
    6   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46f17c8d -[UISearchBar(UISearchBarStatic) _searchFieldReturnPressed] + 72
    7   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47850dfa -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    8   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4722ac22 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 223
    9   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4722af6c -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 398
    10  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47b3b867 -[UIFieldEditor insertFilteredText:] + 298
    11  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47b593cf -[UITextField insertFilteredText:] + 93
    12  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff46f20de4 -[UISearchTextField insertFilteredText:] + 80
    13  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47666421 -[UIKeyboardImpl insertText:] + 147
    14  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47660c19 -[UIKeyboardImpl _performKeyboardOutput:shouldCheckDelegate:] + 1059
    15  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4765f84d __55-[UIKeyboardImpl handleKeyboardInput:executionContext:]_block_invoke_2 + 372
    16  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4768ee0d -[UIKeyboardTaskEntry execute:] + 147
    17  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4768d923 -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue continueExecutionOnMainThread] + 310
    18  Foundation                          0x00007fff25761c40 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 259
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bb2221 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bb214c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 76
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bb1924 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bac62f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23babe16 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff38438bb0 GSEventRunModal + 65
    25  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4784fb48 UIApplicationMain + 1621
    26  HappyBirthdayMom                    0x00000001079869cb main + 75
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff51a1dc25 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

The function should search a Person by its last or first name the order should not matter.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like: `let predicateLastname = NSPredicate(format: "%@ CONTAINS[cd] %@,", nachname, searchTerm!)` But I do not know where nachname or vorname come from.

Comment: both String attributes come from the entity class person - which is managed by Core Data

Comment: Have you tried extracting `vorname` and replacing with `%@` as in my first comment? I'm trying to find a concrete example for you. Will post it if I have success.

Comment: Tried it but as far as i see - NSPredicate only allows 2 Parameters. Appreciate it - thank you

Comment: In `"nachname CONTAINS[cd] %@,`, remove the comma at the end, and it should work.

Comment: Unrelated but why do you downcast `personArray` to more unspecific `[NSManagedObject]` although `fetch` clearly returns `[Person]`?

Comment: Also unrelated, I would use `if let searchTerm = searchBar.text {` and then you don't have to force unwrap `searchTerm` later on.

Comment: thanks for your inputs -  I have adapted the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where lies the error:

```
let predicateLastname = NSPredicate(format: "nachname CONTAINS[cd] %@,", searchTerm!)
```

In fact, if you used only that predicate, you'll still get the error.

Don't put a ",":

```
let predicateLastname = NSPredicate(format: "nachname CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchTerm!)
```

If the comma needs to be in the search text (for an unknown reason),

```
let predicateLastname = NSPredicate(format: "nachname CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchTerm! + ",")
```

Comment: that solved the error - thank you, 
but for some reason the tableview doesn't show the searched terms. Is there something I have missed in the code. At the and I reload the data.